# disable animation in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

If i have a storyboard animation defined in xaml resources, how do i go about disabling it?

For example, if I have something like this on a UserControl.Resources section:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MyKey">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:.5" DecelerationRatio="1" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

IS there a way to disable the animation in xaml..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A XAML way is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741997.aspx

Code behind:
You can use FindResource to get the StoryBoard, cast it to a StoryBoard and call Stop.

**Edit:** See http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx for a deeper look into storyboards and code behind.

**Edit:** Using Properties within triggers:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsActive" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryBoard1}"/>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryBoard2}"/>
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it looks like i have to make use of an event trigger to stop the animation, can i do that by checking for a certain property on a control like a boolean?